# How to catch a text change in wx.stc.StyledTextEvent and update display if forbidden characters appear

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to block all characters which are not basic Latin ([BASIC LATIN](https://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode.php)) and I am using STC in wxpython. The thing is that I tried to bind some events with the STC but there are no events suitable for such a purpose.

None of these events from documentations are recognized - [wx.stc EVENTS](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.stc.StyledTextEvent.html#wx-stc-styledtextevent)
I also tried with EVT_TEXT which works for wx.TextCtrl, but it doesn't work.

I want to try a similar thing as for wx.TextCtrl:

```
import wx
 
class MyForm(wx.Frame):


def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Char Event Tutorial")

    # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
    panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.btn = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="")
    self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onCharEvent)
    self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.forbidChar)


def forbidChar(self, event):
    ## function which should forbid non Latin chars
    print("VALUE: ", self.btn.GetValue())
    
def onCharEvent(self, event):
    
    event.Skip()
    
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I could implement a thread that will use GetValue() from STC and if recognize changes with non-Latin characters, then it should SetValue(data), where data is content with removed non-Latin characters.

Any idea？

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a look at the `string` function.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.__all__
['ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace', 'Formatter', 'Template']
```

Simplistically in action, something like this:

```
import wx
import string
valid = string.printable

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Char Event Tutorial")
    
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.forbidChar)
    
    
    def forbidChar(self, event):
        ## function which should forbid non Latin chars
        text = self.btn.GetValue()
        try:
            char = text[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return
        if char not in valid:
            text = text[:-1]
            wx.MessageBox("Non Latin character", "Error")
            self.btn.Clear()
            self.btn.write(text)
        
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```